# gcc version showing 4.2.1 even after installing 4.9 (Homebrew)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

I installed gcc version 4.9 with homebrew in my mac. But when I check the gcc version in terminal it is showing still the old one.

```
Aarons-MacBook-Air:bin Aaron$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Please help

Comment: by default homebrew installs the compiler with a version postfix, so it's called `gcc-4.9`, so as not to interfere with the system provided compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

homebrew installs gcc with version specific suffixes, so when you install `gcc49`, it gets called `gcc-4.9` on the command line. This is intended to prevent interference with the `gcc` stub (which is actually clang) which is provided by the OSX command line development toolchain, as well as to allow you to install `gcc-4.8`, `gcc-4.7`, etc. alongside each other.

Generally defining the environment variables `CC=gcc-4.9` and `CXX=g++-4.9` should allow you to compile autoconf based packages, as well as standard makefile based projects using the `gcc-4.9` compiler, rather than using the default `cc/gcc`.